# Transpose in Excel while encounter "--------"

Tags: python, excel

I have some data in the same column like the picture below, which split by `---------`
[image]

I want to transpose the column data to row format divided by `-------`, which like the picture below.
[image]

Anyone could give me a hint would be highly appreciated.
And I don't mind using python to solve this problem.

Comment: Using Python is a pretty good choice. There are several approaches you can take with it. I would use the [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) and [XlsxWriter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter) packages (installable using pip if you don't already have them). You could also use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) or [xlwings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwings).

Answer (score 0):

In B15 copied across to suit:

```
=IF($A15="---",OFFSET($A15,COLUMN()-16,),"")
```

and then all formulae copied down to suit. May be convenient then to Copy, Paste Special Values, filter to select `---` and copy as required into another sheet.

`---` represents however many hyphens are appropriate.

Comment: it just blank. Why?

Comment: yes, it worked. Thanks first. But it still needs lots of manual work. I would prefer to look up for some more efficient way.